# AWS mobile hub sign in UI

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub, amazon-mobile-hub

I am newbie for the AWS mobile hub, and really confused with it. I have a database in the mobile hub , and is able to access it. And now I want to add the login view. I have created the pool with a few user account inputted through the mobile hub and integrated. I follow the guide in the AWS , call the build in UI in the viewdidload. When running , the login UI actually pop up , and can detect if the user name and password is not match. However , I pressed the login button , nothing happen, stay on the login view forever. Any one is familiar with this situation ?

```
 if !AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn {
        AWSAuthUIViewController.presentViewController(with: self.navigationController!,
                                   configuration: nil,
                                   completionHandler: { (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        print("Error occurred: \(String(describing: error))")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Sign in successful.")
                                    }
            })
    }
```

delegate is same with the guide

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
    sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
        application, open: url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)

}

func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
            [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
         application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
         launchOptions)
}
```

}

error can not get id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MFVa.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code and any error messages which you get during execution?

Comment: @jing Can you share the code snippet in App Delegate and viewDidLoad method? You can follow the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html#set-up-email-and-password

Comment: @Karthikeyan I just updated my code in viewDidLoad

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Have you added the `awsconfiguration.json` file with your app and added to the sufficient app target? Can you enabled AWSDDLog in AppDelegate and set it to Debug level and see XCode console for logs/exception? Have you created a navigation controller in the app?

Comment: @Karthikeyan I did copy the json file , but it did not work. But anyway , I don't use the build ui now , and use another guide for custom UI. I am able to get a user sign in , but get id failed ,i updated content in my post

Comment: @Karthikeyan I added a image for the error

Comment: Thanks! Got the error image. Have you configured UserPool/Google/Facebook as a sign in provider through MobileHub? Do you have any of this three information in the `awsconfiguration.json file`? Either you have to add one of these three in the mobile hub and re-download the file and add it to the app or enable "Unauthenticated access" in the Identity pool that as related on Cognito console? Thanks!

Comment: @Karthikeyan , I am using the user pool which only allow authenticated access. I got a user , but can not a id returned. Is the setup issue ? What setup needed for user pool ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Just to clarify things: Are you trying to integrate AWS Mobile SDK into your own app? If so, can you download the sample app from mobile hub console and try if it works?

Comment: @jing can you send tell us your mail id or open a customer support case with AWS? we will be able to get you unblocked from the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to take a look at your Cognito user / role policies, The problem is your user pool doesn't support unauthenticated access